# wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) in bicycle gear calculator

Tags: ruby

I'm reading the book "Practical Object-Oriented Design in Ruby" and I have code that is supposed to calculate the optimal gear on a bicycle given its parameters. The book keeps showing the code being set up in many different ways, but never completely. So, in this case, I am given the `initialize` part of the `Gear` class and `Gear.new(...` part at the end. I'm trying to fill in the remaining parts

```
class Gear

  attr_reader :chaingring, :cog, :wheel

  def initialize
    @chainring = args.fetch(:chainring, 40)
    @cog       = args.fetch(:cog, 18)
    @wheel     = args[:wheel]
  end

  def gear_inches
    ratio * diameter
  end

  def ratio
    chainring / cog.to_f
  end

  def wheel
    @wheel ||= Wheel.new(rim, tire)
  end

end

class Wheel

  attr_reader :rim, :tire

  def initialize(rim, tire)
    @rim = rim
    @tire = tire
  end

  def diameter
    rim + (tire * 2)
  end

end

Gear.new(
  :chainring => 52,
  :cog       => 11,
  :wheel     => Wheel.new(26, 2)).gear_inches
```

First of all, it keeps throwing the `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)` error for the last line. Second, I feel like there are other flaws here as well. Such as the user of `diameter` for `gear_inches` method while they belong to different classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Gear` constructor is being called with a hash, but it does not accept a parameter. Replace with:

```
def initialize(args)
```

It is not possible for the code to execute if you keep both the `Gear#initialize` definition and `Gear.new` call unchanged, as they are incompatible with each other.

And, as you suspect, you can't use `diameter`; but you can use `@wheel.diameter` instead.

Comment: yes, adding the arguments to `Gear#initialize` leads to `wrong number of arguments (1 for 3)` error. That's pretty weird, because according to book these two parts are supposed to go together. What are `initialize` and `.new` each compatible with, then?

Comment: `def Klass.initialize()` is compatible with `Klass.new()`; `def Klass.initialize(one)` is compatible with `Klass.new(one)`; `def Klass.initialize(one, two)` is compatible with `Klass.new(one, two)`; etc. Additionally, `def Klass.initialize(one=default_one)` is compatible with both `Klass.new()` and `Klass.new(non_default_one)`. In other words, the parameter count has to match after accounting for any default parameters.

Comment: oh ok, so the problem here is that because of `Wheel.new`, `Gear.new` has two parameters more than in `Gear#initialize`?

Comment: No, they're independent. `Wheel#initialize` is defined to have two parameters, and `Wheel.new` is called with two parameters, so `Wheel` is fine. `Gear` is not fine, since you're calling `new` with "wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)" (i.e. you call it with a hash parameter, but it expects by its definition to receive zero).

Comment: Alright, I got it now, I misread your original response. Now it makes sense. Thank you!